# Bash syntax query: ${*:- "-a"}

Tags: bash, shell-script

I don't understand what it means in a Bash shell script:

```
MYSET=${*:- "-a"}
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter expansion `${variable:-value}` will expand to the string `value` if the variable `variable` is unset or empty.  This is a standard parameter expansion that is not special to the `bash` shell, but that works in all POSIX-compatible shells.

The special variable `$*` is a string consisting of the positional parameters concatenated with the first character of `$IFS` (a space by default) as delimiter.  The positional parameters are the arguments given to the script or shell function, or they are set with the `set` utility, that is, the values `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc.  This too is not `bash`-specific.

Your command sets the variable `MYSET` to `$*` (most likely the command line arguments given to the script, with spaces in-between them), unless this value is empty, in which case `MYSET` will be set to `-a` with an initial space.  The quotes around `-a` makes no difference in this particular case.

Example code on the command line:

```
$ set --
$ MYSET=${*:- "-a"}; printf '%s\n' "$MYSET"
 -a
$ set -- 1 2 3
$ MYSET=${*:- "-a"}; printf '%s\n' "$MYSET"
1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks; but what about "${*" ? Why not "$*" ? Why the "*" is preceded by a "{" ? In Internet I found "$*" and not "${*"

Comment: @user1 Many of the more complex shell expansions would be ambiguous unless they were delineated with braces. Even `$foo1` can be ambiguous: if you have declared `foo=36`, you might expect `$foo1` to be `361`. But it looks for a variable called `foo1`. You needed `${foo}1`.

Comment: @user1 "The internet" is frequently wrong -- in fact, you can find every possible wrong, and right, answer. Which is no answer at all. `https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html` is authoritative.

Comment: @user1 `${*:- "-a"}` is the same as `${variable:-value}` with the `variable` replaced by `*` and `value` replaced by `"-a"`. The `${variable:-value}` expansion is a standard expansion that expands to `$variable` if that value is non-empty, but to the string `value` if `$variable` is empty.  The `${*` bit just happens to be the first three characters of the code `${*:- "-a"}`.  `$*` would be just that, i.e. `$*`, no matter if that's an empty value or not. Here, the developer apparently wanted to provide a default value of `"-a"` if no arguments had been given to the script.  Clearer so?